# Swift UICollectionViewCells with text have odd spacing

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Here is a `UICollectionView` with text in each cell:
[image]

Here is some code attributed to the spacing:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 4.0, height: 20)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}

class ViewThatContainsCollectionView: UIView {

    var delegate: MyDelegate! {
        didSet {
            self.collection_view.delegate = self.delegate
            self.collection_view.dataSource = self.delegate
        }
    }

    var collection_view: UICollectionView!

    let array_of_text: String = [
        "Public",
        "My Crowds",
        "Invite Only",
        "Group"
    ]

    private let title_label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Type:"
        label.textColor = .EVO_text_gray
        label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 18)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.setUpContainerUI()

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        self.collection_view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.collection_view.register(MyCustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MyCustomCell.reuse_identifier)
        self.collection_view.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.collection_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addSubview(self.title_label)
        self.addSubview(self.collection_view)

        self.title_label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        self.title_label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true

        self.collection_view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.collection_view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        self.collection_view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.title_label.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        self.collection_view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setUpContainerUI() {
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = .lightGray
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

}

class MyCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    static let reuse_identifier = "EventCreationMethodCell"

    let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .lightGray
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 15)
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear

        self.addSubview(label)
        self.label.frame = self.bounds
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

If I use text of equal length in each cell, the spacing between each cell looks fine. Here, the length of text varies, so the middle cells appear to be close to each other and the outer cells look a bit far away. Is there anyway to make the cells "appear" to be equally spaced? Please let me know if any more code is necessary. Thanks.

Comment: use a stack view to group all your labels and set the spacing to equal and then put it inside your collectionview. Makes life easy!

Comment: I think your labes has text aligment set to the center. Set a color to the background or use dbug tool to see that there is not space in collection

Comment: @DarkInnocence Could you please give an example of what that would look like?